# localizedString(forRegionCode:) uses a language the app does not support

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, locale

**iPad Settings:**

The language order is:

1. French
2. Chinese

and the region is set to germany.

The **app** supports:

- chinese

The **pod** supports:

- chinese
- french.

Now, in the pod, When I call `NSLocalizedString`s like this:
`NSLocalizedString("Search", tableName: nil, bundle: loginBundle, value: "", comment: "Search")` I get the translation in chinese (as expected).

However, when I call `NSLocale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode:)` I get the country name in french instead of chinese. `NSLocale.current.languageCode` is `"zh"`and `NSLocale.current.regionCode` is `"DE"`

How can I get the country name in the currently used language?

Comment: What's `Locale.current.identifier`?

Comment: @user28434 `Locale.current.identifier` is `zh-Hans_DE`

Comment: Because I need the country name in my current language and not the language name, but I would guess it woult take the same language @PranavKasetti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language used in the app is device-specific first, and then app-specific. So, it uses the most preferred language on the device first, which is also available in the bundle. In particular you can test why the issue is happening by looking at `Locale.preferredLanguages.first`.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html). So, you can get what you're looking for with:

```
Locale(identifier: Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations[0]).localizedString(forRegionCode:)
```

To ensure you set the bundle’s preferred localisation to Chinese, you could also manually select the Locale using Locale(identifier: “zh”). But using the app bundle fixes the issue without hardcoding.

Comment: That’s actually the oposite as what I want

Comment: Could you explain why? I thought the pods first preference language was Chinese.

Comment: The iPad is set to: French,
Chinese. And I want it to show chinese, since the app does not support french

Comment: but the pod's first language would be french, since it uses the order in settings. The pod's languages have no order

Comment: Also, why would it work with `Locale(identifier: loginBundle.preferredLocalizations[0])` with zh, when I am using `Locale.current` with zh and it doesn't?

Comment: It would work if you change it to `Locale(identifier: Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations[0]).localizedString(forRegionCode: code)`, since it would take the language from the app then, please update your answer

Comment: The reason it works is because you initialise the Locale with only the language id and not the full locale identifier. This guarantees the language of the localised string is that language.